# Why am I getting an error to run NPM with HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, https, socket.io

I have define options for SSL certificate but I don't how can I use it in code. so I am not getting proper result with HTTPS URL.
**Here is my code:**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const https = require('https'), fs = require("fs");
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const socketEvents = require('./utils/socket');


const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("/www/wwwroot/securechat.online/nodejs/ssl/privatekey.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("/www/wwwroot/securechat.online/nodejs/ssl/cert1.pem")
};

class Server {
    constructor() {
        this.port = process.env.PORT || 8099;
        this.host = process.env.HOST || 'securechat.online';

        this.app = express();
        this.https = https.Server(this.app);
        this.socket = socketio(this.https);
    }

    appRun(){
        new socketEvents(this.socket).socketConfig();
        this.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
        this.https.listen(this.port, this.host, () => {
            console.log(`Listening on https://${this.host}:${this.port}`);
        });
    }
}

const app = new Server();
app.appRun();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add like below,

```
this.https = https.Server(options, this.app);
```